# HOw should I print the pthread ID in C++?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, pthreads

So I've been trying to get this running but can't figure out what's wrong. My only intention is to create pthreads and output their IDs on the console. Just got started with c++ so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Can you take a look at this and perhaps help me out? Thanks

```
void *printer(void* temp)
{
    pthread_t self_id; 
    int ret;
    self_id=pthread_self();
    printf("\nThis is pthread %u\n",self_id);
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t create;
           int ret;
           ret = pthread_create(&create, NULL, &printer, NULL);
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the 3rd argument to `pthread_create` is the address of the function that is invoked when the new thread starts.  What is `$printer`?

Comment: @bruceg do I have to create a new function like void *printer(void *printer)?

Comment: @DJKHAAAED yes.

Comment: @Swordfish and what parameter should I pass in it to be able to print out the ID?

Comment: @DJKHAAAED You don't have to pass any parameters. Call `pthread_self()` inside your `printer()` to get its thread id.

Comment: @Swordfish thanks for stickin around mate. I edited it to include the function right above main(). Do you think it looks good now?

Comment: @DJKHAAAED Now you're calling `pthread_self()` and discard its return value. Maybe you want to do something with it. Print it, perhaps.

Comment: @DJKHAAAED ``for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)` ... `argc` is the number of parameters passed to your program from the command line. From your "usage"-message i'd assume you want to create `argv[1]` threads instead of `argc` threads.

Comment: @Swordfishyou are correct. I simply aim to give something like ./pthreads 4 as the input on command line. I further modified the function to return and print the value. Thoughts? :)

Comment: Why do you use `<pthread.h>` in C++? It has [`<thread>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) ? Or why use C++ with `pthread.h`? You could use just a C compiler.

Comment: In all cases, compile with all warnings and debug info. Perhaps `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -pthread` or `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -pthread`. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Your `return ret` is wrong in `printer`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you so much for linking that blog post. I appreciate you, btw should I return NULL in that function? btw I'm running this on linux

Comment: You should return a valid pointer (outside of the stack of the thread). That could be `NULL` but also something else. And you should improve your code to get no warnings (with the compilation command mentioned earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 1; i < argv[1]; ++i)
```

is wrong in your `main` (and the `return ret` is wrong in `printer`), because `i` is an integer, but `argv[1]` is of type `char*` so is a pointer. Perhaps you mean (in your `main`):

```
   int n = atoi(argv[1]);
   for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
```

Remember to compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for C++ code, or `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -g` for C code. In C++, you could use [`<thread>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). Improve your code to get no warnings at all. Read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn how to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Notice that `return -1` is bad taste inside your `main` (at least on Linux, see [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and read about the relation between your `main` and the `execve` in your shell). You should return [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) (or use [`exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) on that).

BTW, `pthread_t` is usually some integral type, but the POSIX standard don't specify which one. If you want to print one, in practice you'll better cast it *explicitly* to some wide enough integral type such as `long long` and code `printf("This is pthread %lld\n",(long long) self_id);` which won't give you any warning.

At last, I recommend first learning a programming language (C is much simpler than C++, and you have to choose between both) and use it for sequential programming, and *later* learning [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Parallel thread programming is an advanced topic. By starting with multithreaded programming, you put the bar really too high. Before attempting pthreads, learn the basic sequential programming. See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight.
BTW, if you have never programmed, [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) is an excellent introduction (it does not use C or C++ or threads).

Of course, you don't let your other threads run enough time. You could [`sleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) a bit -in the main thread- before returning from `main`, and you really should wait for your threads, as [explained by Martin York](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52488635/841108).

But I think you need to learn sequential programming before attempting multi-threading.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I should point out that my input will be something like ./pthreads 10 where this '10' is the value that tells my program how many threads it need to create.

Comment: that is not your *input*, but the command running your program

Comment: The only warning that I'm getting right now on compiling is `warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args] printf("\n This is pthread ", self_id);`

Comment: And that is a good warning that you should work on. Of course, read the documentation of [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html). Because of buffering, it is preferable to end `printf` control string with `\n`

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna go ahead and read up on these topics. I appreciate the help

Comment: Your C (in your question) is so rusty that you need to go back to the basics and practice on a few *sequential* programs. I also recommend *reading* and *studying* some *existing* C code from some small free software program (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)...)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is if the "main" thread exits all the child threads will be killed.

So you must make the "main" thread wait until all the children are finished.

```
     pthread_t create;
     int ret = pthread_create(&create, NULL, &printer, NULL);
     if (ret == 0) {
         pthread_join(create, nullptr);  // wait for thread to finish.
     }
```

I would add that this:

```
      i < argv[1]
```

Does not do what you think it does. Note the type of argv is `char*[]`. i.e. it is an array of char pointers. While i is an integer. Now it compiles as integers are easily converted to pointers (but probably generates a warning).

You need to convert the string in `argv[1]` into an integer before you compare it against `i`.

Comment: thank you so much. I went ahead and replaced the argv thing with an integer for the test case. Now I'll change the main